# Don't echo a single command in SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, sqlplus

If I have a script like this...

```
SET ECHO ON

SELECT 'I want the person reading the spool to see this whole query.'
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE interesting_logic_ = 'DEBUGGABLE';

SET ECHO OFF

PROMPT I only want the terminal to show this text, not the PROMPT command.
SELECT '...and this text, without the query' FROM DUAL;
HOST cmd /c echo ...and this text, without the command line

SET ECHO ON
```

How do I keep `SET ECHO OFF` from echoing?

In other words, how do I achieve the equivalent of `@ECHO OFF` from DOS and Windows batch scripting?

Comment: SQLPLUS is really a tool for DBAs and developers to access the database for maintenance and testing. It is not designed for reporting or use by end-users.

Comment: Thanks, Albert. I'm asking because I'd like to save some scrolling when reviewing error messages produced by CREATE PACKAGE BODY statements. (I already use using ANSI escape sequences to color the most important bits to make them stand out.) I use SQL*Plus in lieu of more sophisticated tools because it produces the most reproducible, standardized, portable deployment possible.

Answer (score -1):

Could you redirect the stdout an stderr in host command?

```
HOST ( echo casa ) > /dev/null

[maqui2: ]$ sqlplus  / as sysdba
SQL> HOST ( echo casa ) > /dev/null

SQL>
```